# Dexie: How to reference one dexie db across multiple browsers?

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

Scenario:

1. User opens a Dexie webapp in Firefox.
2. User writes some Dexie data and closes Firefox.
3. User opens same webapp in Chrome.
4. User is able to see the Dexie data that had been added previously in Firefox.

Can Dexie do this?

If Dexie always creates one database per browser, then one workaround might be to read all the relevant Dexie databases on the device and then sync them. I will research that separately in the meantime.

Below is just the beginning of my webapp to show the basics of how I'm currently building the Dexie database. Everything works fine. The only issue is that I'd like the app to always read the same database regardless of which browser I'm in.

```
var db = new Dexie("NameOfDexieDB");

db.version(1).stores({
    table1: '++id, field1'});

db.open().catch (function (e) {
    console.log ("Oh oh: " + e.stack);
});
```

Comment: You may sync using PouchDB/CouchDB.

Answer (score 5):

IndexedDB is local to a single browser. If you want the same data in multiple browsers, you need to sync it with a server.